# Abstract method in oops

Tags: c#, java

Why we are using abstract method because if we have declared abstract class then we must implement that method in derived class that make 2times trouble then why we are not using simple method instead of abstract methods????

Comment: In abstract classes, you can also implment methods.You are using abstract methods to indicate that it has no implementation in the base class but must be implemented in the derived  class.

Answer (score 2):

```
   abstract class Animal 
   {
       abstract public void Voice(); //
   }

   class Dog : Animal
   {
       public void Voice() 
       {
           Console.WriteLine("bark!");
       }
   }

   class Cat: Animal
   {
       public void Voice() 
       {
           Console.WriteLine("meow!");
       }
   }
```

Look at abstract method Voice. What it should be if you imagine that it is abstract animal's voice?

Answer (score 0):

By creating an abstract class which has many subclasses that fulfill the abstract behaviour and maintain the contract of the abstract superclass, you can write methods that are agnostic to the coding implementation of an object, just knowing it will do as told. The different subclasses could get data from different sources, be optimized for different things, have different side effects, etc

If you are learning about object oriented programming school class, then probably like me, none of the principles you learn will make sense - because in small programs, and to make programming examples easily digestable they MUST be small, OOP usually just adds baggage and boilerplate. But the larger your programs get, the more reusable, the more usable in different contexts they must be, the huger and grander and vaster the things they must do and do right, the more OOP techniques simplify the process of coding and thinking about code.

Answer (score 0):

Abstract methods are only allowed to be declared in abstract classes, which means that the classes implementing the abstract class HAS to implement the abstract method, whereas any other method in the abstract class can be overridden, or used as is.

From [abstract (C# Reference)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf985hc5%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

> •Abstract method declarations are only permitted in abstract classes.
>
> •Because an abstract method declaration provides no actual
>   implementation, there is no method body; the method declaration simply
>   ends with a semicolon and there are no curly braces ({ }) following
>   the signature. The implementation is provided by an overriding
>   method [override (C# Reference)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ebca9ah3%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), which is a member of a non-abstract
>   class.

Answer (score 0):

```
abstract class A{
    abstract void method1();
    void method2(){
        //implementation
    }

}

class B extends A{
    public void method1(){
        // implementation
    }
}

class C extends A{
    public void method1(){
        // implementation
    }
}
```

Say B and C is two subclass of A. which have a common method method2 but a different method method1. So you can extend A in both classes. There common method will be inherited automatically. And there you can define your own behavior by implementing method1 in the subclasses.

Comment: @shaktisingh you are welcome. If you think any answer helped you, you can upvote or accept